# Why does window buttons appear twice in Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: unity, compiz, google-chrome, window, window-buttons

After following some beginners tips/tricks for Ubuntu 12.10, I noticed that Chrome/Chromium windows shows the minimize, maximize and close button twice. I tried undoing what I did, but that didn't fix the issue.

Why is it so?

Answer (score -1):

If chromium is not maximized, it will show two sets of {minimize,maximize,close} buttons due to the way it's coded.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer. Everything a program does is "due to the way it's coded." I recommend expanding this to explain how the buttons are built into the side of the tab bar, and also appear due to Unity. (It would be best to provide more details than that, but any amount of detail, including less than this, would probably be helpful.)